# How to merge multiple files of different filetype into single PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

How to merge multiple files of different file type into single PDF using PHP?

For example:

file1.html

file2.docx

files3.jpeg

files4.txt

I want to merge all of the above files into one single PDF file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407598/concatenate-files-in-php)

Comment: Suppose you can solve the html and txt files content, and treat the jpeg with canvas - how you gonna phrase MS Office file with php?