# RecordRTC: merge blobs server-side with PHP

Tags: file-upload, webrtc, blob, recordrtc

I need to build a recording feature on top of a web conferencing app that makes use of WebRTC. To do this I am using the RecordRTC js library.

The recording is NOT uploaded at the end of the call, but for practical reasons every 3 seconds one portion of the stream is uploaded from client to server. This is to avoid waiting at the end for a large upload.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
RTC_recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
    type: 'video',
    mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8',
    timeSlice: 3000,
    ondataavailable: function(blob){
        upload_to_server(blob);
    }
});
```

I have been able to save separate blobs on the server:

```
-blob1.webm (readable video)
-blob2.webm (not readable)
-blob3.webm (not readable)
```

But unfortunately, I don't understand how to merge the blobs into 1 video (SERVER SIDE), and haven't found any working example in the documentation, nor any clear answer to this question.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating the files without any further modification should result in a valid file.

A simple search revealed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407598/concatenate-files-in-php) which was about how concatenating files works in PHP.